# Algebraic complex numbers are countable without using fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I want to prove that the set of all algebraic numbers is countable. I know the proof where we show that the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients is countable (it is the union of $n$ tuples over countable $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is countable), and then that the number of roots of each polynomial is finite, so that the algebraic complex numbers are a countable union of finite sets. I am wondering about other ways to do this.

Can I write any complex number $z=a+bi$ as $z = (1 + (a-1) + bi)$, and then for any polynomial that where $a_0z^n + a_1z^{n-1}+...+a_n = 0$ we have that $n + a_0 + a_1 + \cdots  + a_n + N = 0$  for some real $N$ (but it will have to be an integer). And this is satisfied by a finite number of $N$ and $a_0,...,a_n$.

Comment: I have a feeling you'll end up using the same idea, but just in a more convoluted proof.

Comment: yeah it seems so, I am just wondering if I can avoid using any results about the number of roots of a polynomial.

Comment: It'll be hard, because if the number of roots were uncountable then the result wouldn't hold. For instance, imagine counting the number of 'algebraic pairs' $\langle x,y\rangle$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfy some polynomial equation $P(x,y)=0$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: At some point you'll have to use something specific about the complex numbers. Keep in mind that e.g. in the quaternions the equation $x^2=1$ has uncountably many solutions. So your argument has to somehow not work over the quaternions (and so forth).